# Get the API/pull the Visual Studio Code file language icons into the VS extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, themes, visual-studio-extensions

I am making an extension that is displaying certain items on a tree view, and would like to give them icons representing their language. I would like to not have to save 90 svgs but instead was thinking if there is an api call or some option to get the visual studio code icons directly from the IDE itself, I know there are a lot of icons I can use such as Product icons. If this is not possible, is there a way to get these even if it's in the for of an svg?

I cannot just use  vscode.ThemeIcon.File; since the displayed items are certain code snippets, not entire files.

Comment: Might be helpful: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128507

Comment: @Mark THANK YOU exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `TreeItem` subclass

```
class MyTreeItem extends vscode.TreeItem {
  constructor(item) {
    super(vscode.Uri.file(item.path));
    this.command = { command: "some_command", arguments: [], title: '' };
    this.iconPath = vscode.ThemeIcon.File;
    this.description = true; // use resource URI
    this.label = item.label; // use label when set
  }
}
```

`item` is an object with a `path` member (the `fsPath` of the file uri) and a `label` member.

Now VSC will use the current file icon theme to add icons to the items.

Comment: Thank you, though it finds every tree element as a text object, not a certain file. I would like to be able to manually map items from the api, such as >API['ts'] = vscode.ThemeIcon.File.hypoteticalTSIcon.

Comment: @HannaS what do you mean with `as a text object`, when is it a `file`?

Comment: The list of items in the treeview are not files. They are code snippets, strings pulled from the server, but each code snippet is in a certain language. They are not a file. I pull from the api the text fragment and let's say 'ts' as language given. I want to be able to display the language icon next to the item of the tree. I want to be able to pull the icons from the theme so it stays consistent. the tree is like. this:
>[icon] Typescript
->Snippet 1
->Snippet 2
>[icon] C++
->...
For now Ive custom icons locally but I want to be able to pull them from the theme so it's consistent